# How do I create factories capable of multiple parameters with Zenject?

Tags: zenject

How do I create a factories with zenject with multiple parameter overloaded Create methods (or how to solve this problem differently)?

I want to be able to

```
var x = factory.Create("bla bla");//string
x = factory.Create();//parameterless
x = factory.Create(1);//int
x = factory.Create(1,2);//int,int
x = factory.Create("bla bla",2);//string,int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a factory that includes the maximum number of parameters and then supply extra methods that use default values for the missing values like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Inject]
    public string Value1;

    [Inject]
    public int Value2;

    public class Factory : Factory<string, int, Foo>
    {
        public Foo Create(string value1)
        {
            return Create(value1, 0);
        }

        public Foo Create()
        {
            return Create("default");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks so obvious, I feel a bit unsatisfied that I have not thought of that myself...